# Alternatives to "Or so I thought"?

Tags: word-choice

> That chair was very sturdy, or so I thought.

"Or so I thought" means the previous phrase is wrong after a while of consideration. (or something similar)

Is there  any term/words that can replace "or so I thought" in the same/similar context? (Rephrasing is fine, but not just purely replacing the words, ie. "or so I presumed")

Comment: Is "I errantly believed" too similar?

Comment: or "erroneously"?

Comment: "In my younger and more vulnerable years"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **at first glance**, which has one less syllable.

> when first considering something, before having a chance to look at it carefully
>
> *At first glance the deal looked wonderful, but after reading the fine print he wasn’t so sure.*
>
> [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/at-first-glance)